# Listview shows old and new content after updating

Tags: android, android-listview, listactivity, listadapter, simpleadapter

In my application, listview is loaded from SQLite database and it is using SimpleAdapter to set ListView. When user perform longclick on listitem, that item will be deleted from database and it should update listviw. But when i remove item from database, listview shows both old and new data. 
Please suggest some solution.
Thanx.

Following is my code:

```
public class FavouriteListActivity extends ListActivity {       
    public final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    ListAdapter adapter;
    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsListData = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>(); 
    ArrayList<String> titles = new ArrayList<String>();
    String title,artist;    
    SQLiteAdapter adp;
    SimpleCursorAdapter cursoradp;
    Cursor cursor,cursorDB; 

    @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);      
        setContentView(R.layout.favouritelist);         

        // Adding menuItems to ListView
        final String[] from = {"songTitle", "artist","duration"};
        final int[] to={R.id.fav_songTitle,R.id.fav_songArtist,R.id.fav_duration};

        ListView lv = getListView();            
        songsListData = getFavourites();
        final ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this,songsListData,
                    R.layout.favouritelist_item, from, to);
        lv.setFastScrollEnabled(true);  
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener()
        {
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v,
                     final int pos,final long id) {
                final AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(FavouriteListActivity.this);
                b.setTitle("Are you sure you want to delete?");
                b.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_delete);               
                b.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        String title = songsListData.get(pos).get("songTitle");
                        ListAdapter adapter = null;
                        adp.delete_byTitle(title);
                        songsListData.clear();
                        setListAdapter(null);
                        songsListData = getFavourites();                                                                                         
                        adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getApplicationContext(), songsListData,R.layout.favouritelist_item, from, to);

                        setListAdapter(adapter);
                        Toast.makeText(FavouriteListActivity.this,"Song is removed from Favourites", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
                b.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
                b.show();
                return true;
            }           
        });        
    }
    public ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> getFavourites()
    {
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsListData = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        ArrayList<String> titles = new ArrayList<String>();
        adp = new SQLiteAdapter(this);        
        adp.openToRead();
        cursorDB = adp.queueAll();
        if(cursorDB.moveToFirst())
        {
            for(int i=0;i<cursorDB.getCount();i++)
            {
                titles.add(cursorDB.getString(cursorDB.getColumnIndex("Title")));
                cursorDB.moveToNext();
            }
            String[] songTitles = new String[titles.size()];
            songTitles = titles.toArray(songTitles);
            if(songTitles == null)
            {
                songTitles =null;
            }
            String whereClause = MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + " IN ( ?";
            if (songTitles.length>1) 
            {
                for (int j = 1 ; j < songTitles.length; ++j) 
                {
                    whereClause+=", ?";
                }
            }
            whereClause+=")";             
            Cursor cursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,null ,whereClause,songTitles,MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);            
            if (cursor == null) 
            {
                  //Query Failed , Handle error.
            }
            else if (!cursor.moveToFirst()) 
            {
                 //No media on the device.
            }
            else
            {            
                int titleColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);  
                int idColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);                
                int artistcolumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
                int durationcolumn =cursor.getColumnIndex(android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION);
                for(int i=0;i<cursor.getCount();i++)
                {
                    String thisTitle = cursor.getString(titleColumn);                   
                    String path = cursor.getString(idColumn);
                    String artist = cursor.getString(artistcolumn);
                    Long duration = cursor.getLong(durationcolumn);
                    Utilities objUtilities = new Utilities();
                    String timeDuration = objUtilities.milliSecondsToTimer(duration);   
                    HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    song.put("songTitle",thisTitle);
                    song.put("songPath", path);
                    song.put("artist", artist);
                    song.put("duration",timeDuration);
                    // Adding each song to SongList
                    songsList.add(song);
                    cursor.moveToNext();
                 }
            }
                // looping through playlist
            for (int i = 0; i < songsList.size(); i++) {
                    // creating new HashMap
                HashMap<String, String> song = songsList.get(i);
                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                songsListData.add(song);
            }       
        }
        return songsListData;
    }
}
```

Comment: call intent to the same activity inside the onitemlongclick...

Comment: Just verify the item is deleted from database while calling the below method in your code adp.delete_byTitle(title). One suggestion you don't need to set the adapter again. Instead of that just call notifyDataSetchanged() method once you deleted the item from the list.

Comment: @android.fryo i already tried it ..but  its  not working.

Comment: check if you really delete item from db

Comment: post your delete method here. If delete is success it should return the number of rows affected. In your case what it is returning. If it is 0 means , delete is not successful.

Comment: @Selvin  yup..its removing item from DB.

Comment: are you sure the data is deleted ?

Comment: I suggest the use of TextUtils.join to simplify the construction of the query

Comment: and i suggest to use a while moveToNext instead of a for loop

Comment: Also, your test on songTitle doesn't work and is useless. Useless because toArray doesn't return null, doesn't work because if null it stays null and crashes at songTitle.length.

Comment: also, song = songsList.get(i); doesn't create a new hashMap as your comment suggests, it merely add a reference to an existing one.

Comment: `songsList` is usless, too, you use it only in `getFavourites()` ... you can add song to `songsListData`(the one from  getFavourites() ... i just love your var naming convetion)without first adding it to `songsList` and then coping it to `songsListData`

Comment: @Selvin...i am sure that data is deleted and that's why i said that its showing old and new data. Please read my question carefully.    And I am using hashmap in another activity of my application.Therefore, i have created this songListData.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never clear songList, to which therefore is added all your items at each deletion.

Which in turn are all copied to songsListData.

Comment: and `songList` is in `FavouriteListActivity`  not `getFavourites` ... so yeap this is a good answer ... not guessing like others .. @njzk2 good eye anyway its hard to get through this code ...

Answer (score 0):

After removing data from the database , call

```
Listview.invalidateViews();
```

and reset the adapter to the list .

Actually it gets removed from the database but it shows the older list in the ListView , so invalidate your older views and reset the adapter .

Comment: what for? and where he is already setting adapter in his code `setListAdapter(adapter);
                        Toast.makeText(FavouriteListActivity.this,"Song is removed from Favourites", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();` ... and setting adapter will ends with removing all view from layout anyway ...

Answer (score -2):

Call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() every time your data changes.

```
b.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        String title = songsListData.get(pos).get("songTitle");                        
                        adp.delete_byTitle(title);
                        songsListData.clear();
                        setListAdapter(null);
                        songsListData = getFavourites();                                                                                         
                        adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getApplicationContext(), songsListData,R.layout.favouritelist_item, from, to);

                        setListAdapter(adapter);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        Toast.makeText(FavouriteListActivity.this,"Song is removed from Favourites", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
```

Comment: what for? he is creating new adapter 2 line before your adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() ... it will not help